# Excel VBA 450 Error on "End Function" Line

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm getting an Error 450 "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".  The error occurs at the very end of the function, the very last line "End Function".  I don't see any missing "End Ifs" so I have no clue what's causing this:

```
 myDict = bpCreateDictionary("A", "B", 1, 10, "Sheet2", , "Ignore")
```

Which references this function:

```
Function bpCreateDictionary(ByVal KeyColumn As String, ByVal ValueColumn As String, _
         Optional ByVal RowBegin As Long, Optional RowEnd As Long, _
         Optional ByVal DataWorksheet As String = "Sheet1", _
         Optional ByVal DataWorkbook As String, _
         Optional ByVal HandleDuplicates As String, _
         Optional ByVal KeepOpen As Boolean = False) As Dictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sCurrentActiveBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    sCurrentActiveSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim oDictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lIncrementer As Long
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim vValue As Variant

    If Not DataWorkbook = "" Then
        oWorkbookName = bpGetFilenameFromPath(DataWorkbook)
        Workbooks.Open (DataWorkbook)
        Workbooks(oWorkbookName).Activate
        sCurrentActiveExternalSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    End If

    If Not DataWorksheet = "" Then
        Worksheets(DataWorksheet).Activate
    End If

    If Not RowEnd = 0 Then
        lLastRow = RowEnd
    Else
        lLastRow = bpLastRow(KeyColumn)
    End If

    If RowBegin = 0 Then
        RowBegin = 1
    End If

    For lIncrementer = RowBegin To lLastRow
        vKey = Cells(lIncrementer, KeyColumn)
        vValue = Cells(lIncrementer, ValueColumn)
            If HandleDuplicates = "Ignore" And oDictionary.Exists(vKey) Then
                'Do Nothing and move to next row
            Else
                oDictionary.Add vKey, vValue
            End If
    Next lIncrementer

    Set bpCreateDictionary = oDictionary

    If Not oWorkbookName = "" Then
        If Not KeepOpen = True Then
            Worksheets(sCurrentActiveExternalSheet).Activate
            Workbooks(oWorkbookName).Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    End If

    Workbooks(sCurrentActiveBook).Activate
    Worksheets(sCurrentActiveSheet).Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

And on that last line "End Function" is where the error occurs when debugging.  Any ideas on what may be going on here?

Comment: `Set myDict = bpCreateDictionary(...)`?

Comment: That was it GSerg, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you did in the function where you

```
Set bpCreateDictionary = oDictionary
```

you have to

```
Set myDict = bpCreateDictionary("A", "B", 1, 10, "Sheet2", , "Ignore").
```

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've made this same mistake, thanks for pointing it out!